# Conditional expectation of a smaller filtration

Tags: brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, stochastic-analysis, filtrations

I am trying to solve the following problem.

Let $\mathcal{F}_t$ be the filtration generated by a Brownian motion $W$, and $\theta$ be a random variable on the same sample space $\Omega$, independent of $W$. Define an initially enlarged filtration $\mathcal{G}_t = \mathcal{F}_t \vee \sigma(\theta)$.

Now let $X$ be a $\mathcal{G}_s$-meaurable random variable. My question is, do I have
$\mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{F}_t] = \mathbb{E}[X\vert \mathcal{F}_s]$? I tried to use $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem but failed.

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are $s$ and $t$ related?

Comment: If, as I suspect, you intend $0<s<t$, then a good start can be made by using a monotone class argument to show that $X$ can be represented as $X(\omega)= f(\omega,\theta(\omega))$, where $f:\Omega\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is $\mathcal F_s\otimes\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$-measurable. (I'm assuming, for definiteness, that $\theta$ is real valued.)

Answer (score 0):

I presume we have $0\leq s\leq t < \infty$.

Note that trivially,
$$
\mathcal{F}_s \, \perp \!\!\! \perp \, \mathcal{F}_t \, \mid \, \mathcal{F}_s.
$$
Since $\theta \perp \!\!\! \perp W$ and $\mathcal{F}_s \subset \mathcal{F}_t$, it also holds that
$$
\sigma(\theta) \, \perp \!\!\! \perp \, \mathcal{F}_t \, \mid \, \mathcal{F}_s.
$$
Collecting results,
$$
\mathcal{G}_s \, \perp \!\!\! \perp \, \mathcal{F}_t \, \mid \, \mathcal{F}_s.
$$
In other words, for any $A\in\mathcal{G}_s$ it holds that
$$
\mathbb{P}(A \, | \, \mathcal{F}_t) = \mathbb{P}(A \, | \, \mathcal{F}_s).
$$
By classic extension (monotone class argument),
$$
\mathbb{E}[X \, | \, \mathcal{F}_t] = \mathbb{E}[X \, | \, \mathcal{F}_s]
$$
for any $\mathcal{G}_s$-measurable random variable $X$ with finite expectation.

If you're not too familiar with conditional independence, please let me know.